# Raspberry + Sensor to Plotly HOW? Python

Tags: python, plotly, sensors, raspberry-pi3

save my life.
PYTHON+RASPI!
I have some problems. I have raspberry pi 3 + Ultrasound Sensor HC-SR04. I am reading distance from it and want to use live-data chart in plot.ly but can't figure out how :/ I have found working code for distance calculation written in python readadc.py.:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import signal
import sys

# use Raspberry Pi board pin numbers
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

# set GPIO Pins
pinTrigger = 23
pinEcho = 24

def close(signal, frame):
    print("\nTurning off ultrasonic distance detection...\n")
    GPIO.cleanup() 
    sys.exit(0)

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, close)

# set GPIO input and output channels
GPIO.setup(pinTrigger, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(pinEcho, GPIO.IN)

while True:
    # set Trigger to HIGH
    GPIO.output(pinTrigger, True)
    # set Trigger after 0.01ms to LOW
    time.sleep(0.00001)
    GPIO.output(pinTrigger, False)

    startTime = time.time()
    stopTime = time.time()

    # save start time
    while 0 == GPIO.input(pinEcho):
        startTime = time.time()

    # save time of arrival
    while 1 == GPIO.input(pinEcho):
        stopTime = time.time()

    # time difference between start and arrival
    TimeElapsed = stopTime - startTime
    # multiply with the sonic speed (34300 cm/s)
    # and divide by 2, because there and back
    distance = (TimeElapsed * 34300) / 2

    print ("Distance: %.1f cm" % distance)
    time.sleep(1)
```

[In this picture i have my distance values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5idRG.png)

Now I need to make connection to plotly. I have made it, i am connecting,  but how to send values for drawing? I cant understand.. Here is my first part of code for plotly connection:

```
import plotly.plotly as py
from plotly.graph_objs import Scatter, Layout, Figure
import time
import readadc

username = 'here_i_write_my_username'
api_key = 'here_i_write_my_api'
stream_token = 'here_i_write_my_token'

py.sign_in(username, api_key)

trace1 = Scatter(
    x=[],
    y=[],
    stream=dict(
        token=stream_token,
        maxpoints=200
    )
)

layout = Layout(
    title='Raspberry Pi Streaming Sensor Data'
)

fig = Figure(data=[trace1], layout=layout)

print py.plot(fig, filename='Raspberry Pi Streaming Example Values')
```

And i have no idea what to do next? How to send only 1 row data without X and Y ?  I was trying something like this but it don't work. Can somebody help to end the code?

Not working try, plot nothing, empty chart:

```
sensor_pin = 24
readadc.initialize()

i = 0
stream = py.Stream(stream_token)
stream.open()

#the main sensor reading loop
while True:
        sensor_data = readadc.readadc(sensor_pin,readadc.pinEcho)
        stream.write({'x': i, 'y': sensor_data})
        i += 1
        # delay between stream posts
        time.sleep(0.5)
```

Answer (score -1):

Nevermind. I've done . Everything works just fine